# Azure Backup Recovery Slow

Tags: backup, azure, microsoft, azure-backup

I am currently restoring from the Azure Backup cloud as a mounted drive using the Azure Backup Utility. I am copying files from the mounted drive to the local drive using robocopy as suggested by Microsoft. The recovery speed is extremely slow. (7.43GB) in 4 hours. I need to restore ~90GB.
What am I missing here?
Azure backup is up to date, no proxy, internet speed is adequate, CPU, RAM, DISK utilization is low.
I am running Windows Server 2016.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this is a standard storage account then you could be just getting throttled by the IO limits on the storage account.